# Upgraded installation from Wheezy to Jessie; unable to SSH into Pi now

Tags: raspbian, ssh, raspbian-wheezy, raspbian-jessie, rpi-update

I have hit a wall with regard to this issue and I have no inkling whatsoever as to what might have happened. Any help regarding this matter will be greatly appreciated.

I connect to my Raspberry Pi 2 over the network, SSH-ing into it. Today, I tried upgrading the from the wheezy version to Jessie by changing the /etc/apt/sources.list file and using apt-get dist-upgrade. Installation finished normally, with no exceptions. I restarted the Pi and now I can't seem to SSH into it anymore. Trying to ping it returns a request timeout message. I don't have a display to connect my raspberry pi to, so I don't have anymore information to give regarding this issue, only that I can't even ping it anymore! I apologize for the clueless post, but I really can't think of where to even begin troubleshooting.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, check if it's booting and reaching the network. It may just have a different ip, depending how your network is set up.

`nmap` is a great linux tool for finding ip's of devices on the local network. Type

```
nmap 192.168.1.1-255
```

in your command line to list all devices on your network with last 3 digits 1-255. From here, you should see your pi. If you are unable to locate it, there may be an issue while booting and a directly connected display may be needed.

Also, if you are using wifi to connect, double check to make sure your drivers are still installed and working. If you *are* able to find it, it should be as easy as changing the address you are using ssh to reach.